# Remove elements from list of lists based on condition

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a list of lists (from a certain column of a dataframe where each element of col is a list) which I transformed to an array of shape (2819, 11).
[image]

I am trying to find code that does not include for loops, to eliminate lists that include np.nan

Comment: All rows that contain only nan?

Comment: No, rows that contain at least one value as np.nan

Comment: Your data looks like a dataframe. Do you want to apply this on whole column?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`np.isnan()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html) combined with [`any()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) to index only the rows you want:

```
l = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1, np.nan, 4],
    [5, 6, 7],
    [np.nan, np.nan, 7]
])


l[~(np.isnan(l).any(axis=1))]

#array([[1., 2., 3.],
#       [5., 6., 7.]])
```

This uses `~` to invert the boolean values from `isnan()` so you get the rows where it is false.

Comment: For my own sanity, I'd probably write `~(np.isnan(l).any(..))` just because `(~np.isnan(l)).any(..)` means something completely different, and I want to make sure the code is completely unambiguous.

Comment: That's a good point @FrankYellin, I edited to include this. Thank you.